# Store slices and nested structures in MongoDB Golang

Tags: arrays, mongodb, go, bson

I have built a program in Go with the next structure

```
type A struct {
  feature []string
}

type B struct {
  title string
  other_feature []A
}
```

I tried to use the bson package but only the title appears on the database after execution. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you share more code / please specify the mongo DB driver you're using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [golang mongodb (mgo) is not inserting docs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045404/golang-mongodb-mgo-is-not-inserting-docs)

Answer (score 5):

You need to [export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the field names by starting the field name with an uppercase letter. Use the bson field tag to specify the named used in the database.

```
type A struct {
  Feature []string `bson:"feature"`
}

type B struct {
  Title string       `bson:"title"`
  Other_feature []A  `bson:"other_feature"`
}
```